# How to drag the cell on right in UITableView when tap, like in Snapchat?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In Snapchat application on the main screen if you tapped on a cell with contact - the cell will drag from left to right (look at the screen). How I can do this?

P.S. The similar effect has an iOS lock screen when you tap on the Camera on the right bottom corner.

Thanks in advanced.[image: Snapchat main screen]

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add `panGestureRecognizer` to your `tableView`.
2. Track the gesture recognizer states, and check for `translation.x` value to see the position of drag.
3. Get the view of the drag = the cell you have.
4. Shift the position of the cell based on that `translation.x` value, and at that time, move whatever view you want to show beneath it.  [Note:  if you want that view to slide from left to right, then use the `translation.x` value.
5. Check for threshold of movement, if that exceeds, then leave the view open. If that does not exceed, animate that view so that the cell's frame is set back to normal.

[You can also use the `velocity` property along with `translation` - gives user a better experience. Its the same as swipe]

P.s. If you still don't get it, I suggest you just look up google 'ios uitableviewcell swipe to reveal` I am sure you will find plenty of examples.

Peace.

Comment: Also, your battery is at 10%. Don't forget to recharge your phone.

Comment: Sure! Thanks a lot :)
Quite hard solution :)